# Custom Box Environment

Tags: environments, framed

I'm currently writing a report and I need to create a custom "Box" environment similar to that shown in the figure below. For the sake of objectivity the following requirements are the only ones I'm looking for:

1. The contents are to be framed (which I guess it can be achieved using the `framed` package);
2. It should have a Per Chapter counter (i.e. if currently at the Chapter 2, the third box should be numbered Box 2.3)
3. The caption should be equal to the standard figure caption EXCEPT it should appear on top instead.

I would appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `float` more or less offers what you want, even a boxed style. It seems, however, that one has to define a new style `boxedtop` in order to have the caption appear on top of the box, like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@boxedtop
  {\fs@boxed
   \def\@fs@mid{\vspace\abovecaptionskip\relax}%
   \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
  }
\makeatother
```

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@boxedtop
  {\fs@boxed
   \def\@fs@mid{\vspace\abovecaptionskip\relax}%
   \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
  }
\makeatother
\floatstyle{boxedtop}
\floatname{framedbox}{Box}
\newfloat{framedbox}{tbp}{lob}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{framedbox}[htbp]
  \caption{The Newton-Raphson whatever}
  \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{framedbox}

\lipsum[2]
\listof{framedbox}{List of Boxes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** If you don't want to have the caption title in boldface, change the definition of the style `boxedtop` to

```
\newcommand\fs@boxedtop
 {\fs@boxed
  \def\@fs@mid{\vspace\abovecaptionskip\relax}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
  \def\@fs@cfont{\rmfamily}%
 }
```

(Note the added last line.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, didn't know about float package. Thanks! Is there any way I can format the caption so that it's not bold?

Comment: Based on what I read, the caption formating is still externally formated using caption package for example. Once again, thank you for your quick and useful answer!

Comment: @BernardoFerreira I don't know whether the `float` and the `caption` package work well together; it's certainly worth a try. Otherwise I have added a remark to my solution that shows how to change the caption title to normal font (without the `caption` package).

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not said which class to be used I took a standard with chapter division.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{float,framed,lipsum}
\newfloat{Box}{h}{lob}[chapter]
\newenvironment{Mybox}{\begin{Box}\begin{framed}}{\end{framed}\end{Box}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Mybox}
\caption{My caption}
This is a boxed float
\end{Mybox}

\chapter{Other chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{Mybox}
\caption{Some caption}
Another boxed float
\end{Mybox}

\end{document}
```

You can check the [`float`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) manual for more info on how to customize floats.